# Как реализовать алгоритм имитации полета светлячков?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, графика

Например, вокруг фонаря) ну, или иного объекта, думаю, многие из вас видели, как летают всякие насекомые около, светящейся в ночи, лампы. В общем, нужно как-то математически описать траекторию полета этих "светлячков", и добавить хаотичности, т.к. просто летать по кругу не очень-то и интересно) вот взять "светлячка", ему обязательно хочется коснуться, да и прям-таки обжечься об лампу, а то и вовсе сгореть бесследно, это уж как повезет) то есть, нужна живость данного алгоритма) хотя, на первых порах, я и от обычного полета по кругам не откажусь. Может у кого есть ссылки на нужную литературу или блогозапись, готовая к реализации идея, или просто подсказка? Всему буду рад)

Comment: светлячки сами светятся, на свет не особо летят.

Comment: мотыльки, да. разбить алгоритм на несколько частей. мотылек - увидел свет, полетел к нему (по ломаной - от взмаха крыльев, притом параболе - сила тяжести и все такое); стукнулся о лампочку, упал тоже по параболе - отскочил; покружил по спирали, сел на лампочку сгорел; дым, пепел падает на пол; из пепла вылетает новый мотылек, а то и два.  

:)

Comment: Честно признаюсь, давно не наблюдал, но по моим воспоминаниям их мельтешение на броуновское движение не очень похоже.


Может попробовать понять стимулы, которые движут "светлячками"?

 Т.е. по сути моделировать их нервную систему и внешние сигналы.

Тогда будет ясно в действия каких сил надо вносить случайные возмущения.

Comment: Наверное, это не то, что Вам нужно, но всё-таки...
[Fireflies](https://github.com/motyar/firefly)

Comment: Дополню: у этого проекта открытый исходный код, поэтому вы легко сможете модифицировать его на свой вкус или скачать готовую модификацию от других пользователей.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, хороший плагин, внешне близок к тому, что мне нужно, спасибо)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, феникс-мотылек)
а движение по параболе весьма кстати)

Comment: Включи переменную вечность - вот тебе и алгоритм движения.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Где-то читал что навигационная система светлячков устроена так: они летят под определенным углом к источнику света (в идеале к Луне). В случае бесконечного далекого объекта это дает некую прямую линию, а если источник света близкий (фонарь, костер) то светлячки движутся по спирали и в конце-концов обжигаются и падают.

Мне кажется вполне себе алгоритм: надо задаться навигационным углом светлячка + его скоростью полета. В вырожденном случае, если навигационный угол равен 90 градусам, светлячок будет летать по кругу, если угол 0 градусов - будет лететь прямиком к свету. Легко можно добавить хаотичности: немного случайно менять навигационный угол в зависимости от скорости полета или что-нить такое.

Comment: @Barmaley, ваш вариант описания алгоритма очень даже неплох) в голове сразу возникли идеи по реализации (до этого даже понятия не имел что и как), вырисовывается картинка, как мотыльки появляются на разных концах холста я тянутся к лампе (не прямо к ней, а к произвольной точке невидимого шара, внутри которого находится лампа, шар будет иметь размеры 2x, x3 от размера лампы), после приближения "мотылек" начнет движение по спирали (+ всякие возмущения) после чего его ждет смерть (или пощада в виде выключения лампы), спасибо) примусь за реализацию технической стороны)

Comment: Можете ещё добавить «временную слепоту» – приблизившись ближе x к лампе, свтетлячок может «ослепнуть» и отклониться в случайном направлении и лететь так некоторое время, пока «зрение» не вернётся.

Comment: И ещё, лампа – не точка. Её угловой размер с т.з. светлячка увеличивается по мере приближения, давая ему доп. свободу в 
выборе направления.  **Ой, некропост**, только сейчас заметил год.